# .htaccess rewrite dynamically GET variables from a search query

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following URL on my website:

> www.domain.com/index.php?id=42&f_su_ort=PLZ%2C+Ort+oder+Name+der+Einrichtung&f_sop_name=Name+der+Einrichtung&f_sop_traeg=0&f_su_ent=10&f_sp_111=on&f_sp_121=on&f_sp_131=on&f_sp_141=on&f_sp_151=on&f_sp_161=0&f_sp_112=112&f_sp_211=on&f_sp_221=on&f_sp_231=on&f_sp_241=on&f_sp_251=on&f_sp_212=on&f_sp_213=on&f_sp_222=on&f_sp_223=on&f_sp_232=on&f_sp_ang=&f_su_submit2=Suchen&f_sp_karte=on

That is generated from a search query, which can have multiple parameters and the number of parameters is not fixed.

Any ideas how I can make it with .htaccess so that instead of `variable=value` look `/value`
e.g.

> www.domain.com/index.php?id=42&f_su_ort=Berlin

should translate to

> www.domain.com/42/Berlin

I only have a possibility to edit the .htaccess file, not the script.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the parameters always in the same order ? Do you require f_su_ort to have the parameters after it ?

Comment: It's not the same order.

Comment: Then you can't. How would you know which one is corresponding otherwise ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).....$ http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=$1&f_su_ort=$2..... [L,QSA]
```